# Use jest.spyOn with mockImplementation to throw an Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have a function called read within *index.ts* that uses Node.js **promisify** from the util module. The read function is surrounded by a *try/catch* and I would like to test, using jest, that when code fails console.error is called.

#### index.ts/read

```js
export async function read(): Promise<string> {
    try {
        const readFileProm = promisify(readFile);
        const content = await readFileProm(__filename);
        console.log(content.toString());
        return content.toString();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

#### testcase (jest)

```js
import { read, add } from '../src/index';
import * as util from 'util';

    describe(`Read Function`, () => {
        it(`should call 'console.error' with error message 'An error has occurred'`, async () => {
            const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error');
            jest.spyOn(util, 'promisify')
                .mockImplementation(() => { throw new Error('An error has occurred')});
            await read();
            expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('An error has occurred');
        });
    });
```

According to the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname), I can spyOn and mock the implementation of the promisify function and what I'm expecting to happen is it throw an error, but no error is thrown causing the test case to fail. When I debug it goes the promisify function goes right to the next line. How can I mock the promisify with jest so that it causes throws the error causing the catch block to run the console.error to run?

Comment: Irrelevant for your question, but still worth mentioning: `import { readFile } from 'node:fs/promises';`

Comment: @robertklep updated the test file. thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you understood, but instead of using `util.promisify()` on an `fs` method, Node.js provides a Promise-based implementation directly.

Comment: @robertklep I am aware of the promise based methods in the fs module. Thanks!